# Why does my program exit unexpectedly when I call input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this RPG program to work, but I can't figure it out. I run it and well, you will see when you run the program. For some reason when I run this it stops at 1,2,3,4 after every move I make. Am I not returning anything? What am I doing wrong here, and how can I improve my organization and code in the future?

```
import math

import random


class character:
    def __init__(self, hp, max_hp, att, exp, int):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.att = att
        self.exp = exp
        self.int = int

class enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, max_hp, att, exp, int):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.att = att
        self.exp = exp
        self.int = int




charspells = ['Fireball']
Loop = True

def fireball(character, enemy):
    enemy.hp -= character.int
    print('You did, ',character.int ,'to the enemy')
    print('Enemy.hp', enemy.hp)
    return enemy.hp

items = []

mainc = character(100, 100, 10, 0, 10)
tai_lopez = enemy(30, 30, 5, 0, 10)

def character_battle(character, enemy):
    choice = input('What would you like to do?\n 1. Attack \n 2. Spells \n 3. Items \n 4. Run')
    if choice == input('1'):
        print('You attack the enemy!')
        enemy.hp -= character.att
        print('You dealt', character.att, 'to the enemy!')
        print('Enemy hp =', enemy.hp)
    if choice == input('2'):
        spellchoice = input('Which spell do you wish to call?')
        print('1.', charspells[0],'\n' '2.', charspells[1], '\n' 'q', 'exit')
        if spellchoice == ('1'):
            print('You used fireball!')
            fireball(character, enemy)

        elif spellchoice == ('2'):
            if charspells[1] != 'Lightning bolt':
                print('It doesnt exist, sorry')
                # ill add more spell fucntions later
        if spellchoice == ('3'):
            print('You went back to the menu')
    if choice == input('3'):
        if items == []:
            print('You have no items')
        if items == ['potions']:
            print ('response')
            #placeholder ill add the fucntion later
    elif choice == input('4'):
        Loop = False

def enemy_battle(enemy, character):
    a = random.randint(0,50)
    if a <= 35:
        print('The enemy attacks you!')
        character.hp -= enemy.att
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)
    elif a <= 50:
        print('The enemy uses mind attacks bruh')
        character.hp -= enemy.int
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)

def battle_loop(character, enemy):
    Loop1 = True
    while Loop1 == True:
        while enemy.hp > 0  and character.hp > 0:
            character_battle(character, enemy)
            enemy_battle(character, enemy)
            if enemy.hp <= 0:
                print('You Won')
                Loop1 =  False
            if character.hp <= 0:
                print('You lost')
                exit()



battle_loop(mainc, tai_lopez)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `input()` in if statement. Whenever interpreter tries to check if condition is true or not it executes the `input()` which demands an input even when you didn't expect it. In one of the methods your input was in wrong order so I fixed that too. So correct code should be :-

```
import math

import random


class character:
    def __init__(self, hp, max_hp, att, exp, int):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.att = att
        self.exp = exp
        self.int = int

class enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, max_hp, att, exp, int):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.att = att
        self.exp = exp
        self.int = int




charspells = ['Fireball']
Loop = True

def fireball(character, enemy):
    enemy.hp -= character.int
    print('You did, ',character.int ,'to the enemy')
    print('Enemy.hp', enemy.hp)
    return enemy.hp

items = []

mainc = character(100, 100, 10, 0, 10)
tai_lopez = enemy(30, 30, 5, 0, 10)

def character_battle(character, enemy):
    choice = input('What would you like to do?\n 1. Attack \n 2. Spells \n 3. Items \n 4. Run \n')
    if choice == '1':
        print('You attack the enemy!')
        enemy.hp -= character.att
        print('You dealt', character.att, 'to the enemy!')
        print('Enemy hp =', enemy.hp)
    elif choice == '2':
        spellchoice = input('Which spell do you wish to call?')
        print('1.', charspells[0],'\n' '2.', charspells[1], '\n' 'q', 'exit')
        if spellchoice == ('1'):
            print('You used fireball!')
            fireball(character, enemy)

        elif spellchoice == ('2'):
            if charspells[1] != 'Lightning bolt':
                print('It doesnt exist, sorry')
                # ill add more spell fucntions later
        if spellchoice == ('3'):
            print('You went back to the menu')
    elif choice == '3':
        if items == []:
            print('You have no items')
        if items == ['potions']:
            print ('response')
            #placeholder ill add the fucntion later
    elif choice == '4':
        Loop = False

def enemy_battle(character, enemy):
    a = random.randint(0,50)
    if a <= 35:
        print('The enemy attacks you!')
        character.hp -= enemy.att
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)
    elif a <= 50:
        print('The enemy uses mind attacks bruh')
        character.hp -= enemy.int
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)

def battle_loop(character, enemy):
    Loop1 = True
    while Loop1 == True:
        while enemy.hp > 0  and character.hp > 0:
            character_battle(character, enemy)
            enemy_battle(character, enemy)
            if enemy.hp <= 0:
                print('You Won')
                Loop1 =  False
            if character.hp <= 0:
                print('You lost')
                exit()



battle_loop(mainc, tai_lopez)
```

You didn't need two classes here clearly. But I suppose you might be thinking of adding some more features in future I guess. You can study more about oop and inheritance and figure out a smarter solution in general. I think you should focus on basics. Also try not to name the temporary variable same as that of class. It is a very hastly written code imo. But I fixed it's working.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Yeah i kinda wrote in in an hour and i was wondering why it wasnt working. Thanks for the tips though, Im happy someone responded. OOP and inheritance is good to know

Answer (score 0):

Looks interesting, send me a copy after you finish will ya?
so basically you use too much input()
you have to enter a value for every input() function
you need to organize your code, maybe look at how others write their code
 
this is a quick fix, but it doesn't mean that this is the standard, you still have a lot to learn

```
import random

class character:
    def __init__(self, hp, max_hp, att, exp, int):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.att = att
        self.exp = exp
        self.int = int

charspells = ['Fireball','iceblock']
Loop = True
items = []
mainc = character(100, 100, 10, 0, 10)
tai_lopez = character(30, 30, 5, 0, 10) # enemy

def fireball(character, enemy):
    enemy.hp -= character.int
    print('You did, ',character.int ,'to the enemy')
    print('Enemy.hp', enemy.hp)
    return enemy.hp

def character_battle(character, enemy):
    choice = input('What would you like to do?\n 1. Attack \n 2. Spells \n 3. Items \n 4. Run')
    if choice == '1':
        print('You attack the enemy!')
        enemy.hp -= character.att
        print('You dealt', character.att, 'to the enemy!')
        print('Enemy hp =', enemy.hp)
    if choice == '2':
        print('Which spell do you wish to call?')
        print('1.', charspells[0],'\n' '2.', charspells[1], '\n' 'q', 'exit')
        spellchoice = input()
        if spellchoice == ('1'):
            print('You used fireball!')
            fireball(character, enemy)
        elif spellchoice == ('2'):
            if charspells[1] != 'Lightning bolt':
                print('It doesnt exist, sorry')
                # ill add more spell fucntions later
        if spellchoice == ('3'):
            print('You went back to the menu')
    if choice == '3':
        if items == []:
            print('You have no items')
        if items == ['potions']:
            print ('response')
            #placeholder ill add the fucntion later
    elif choice == '4':
        print("You cowardly run away")
        exit()

def enemy_battle(enemy, character):
    a = random.randint(0,50)
    if a <= 35:
        print('The enemy attacks you!')
        character.hp -= enemy.att
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)
    else:
        print('The enemy uses mind attacks bruh')
        character.hp -= enemy.int
        print('Your hp =', character.hp)

def battle_loop(character, enemy):
    Loop1 = True
    while Loop1:
        while enemy.hp > 0  and character.hp > 0:
            character_battle(character, enemy)
            enemy_battle(character, enemy)
            if enemy.hp <= 0:
                print('You Won')
                Loop1 =  False
            if character.hp <= 0:
                print('You lost')
                exit()

battle_loop(mainc, tai_lopez)
```